# Loading a TensorFlow frozen graph (.pb) in Node.js

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I saved a tensorflow model in a frozen PB file which is suitable to be used by TensorFlow Lite.
This file can be loaded in Android and works well by following code:

`import org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface;
…
TensorFlowInferenceInterface inferenceInterface;
inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(context.getAssets(), "MODEL_FILE.pb");`

Is there any way to load the frozen graph in Node.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter):
1. the model must be converted to a web-friendly format which is a JSON file.
2. Then can be loaded using '@tensorflow/tfjs' in Nodejs.